# How to create a browse button

Tags: asp.net

How can a ASP.NET button be used to browse and upload items from my computer? Using C# language if needed.

Comment: you need to be a bit more specifi in what you are asking here before we can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438485/file-upload-control-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `<asp:Button />` for that. You should use the `<asp:FileUpload />` control instead.

The `myUploadControl.FileBytes` then contains the byte array containing the file data.